# Intuitive explanation why Lebesgue measure of irrationals in [0,1] equals 1

Tags: lebesgue-measure, irrational-numbers

I came up with the following intuitive explanation why the irrational numbers in the interval [0,1] have measure 1 and would like to know if the explanation is correct.

- the Lebesgue measure requires a *countable* union of disjoint
  intervals to cover all irrationals in the interval [0,1]
- the irrationals are uncountable
- Therefore, the (countable) intervals in the measure need to be of
  non-zero length to cover all irrationals
- since the whole interval needs to be covered the lengths sum to one

Any evaluation is appreciated

habbes

Comment: There exist uncountable sets of zero Lebesgue measure (e.g. the Cantor ternary set).

Comment: Note that uncountable, dense subsets of $[0,1]$ exist with measure $0$. Consider the Cantor Ternary set and take its union with the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, but I am only referring to the real interval [0,1]

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean by "the Lebesgue measure requires a countable union of disjoint intervals to cover all irrationals in the interval [0,1] ".

Let $A$ be the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and $B$ be the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$.

Then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $A \cup B=[0,1]$, hence

$1= \lambda([0,1])= \lambda(A)+ \lambda(B)=\lambda(B)$,

since $\lambda(A)=0$.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the (outer) measure is defined as a countable union of intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Know $\lambda([0,1]) = 1$. Since we know that the rationals have Lebesgue measure zero, removing something with zero measure from $[0,1]$ maintains the original measure.

Basically: $\lambda([0,1]\cap \mathbb{I}) = \lambda([0,1]-\mathbb{Q}) = 1-0=1$